# How to handle yodlee MFA?

Tags: yodlee

There's almost no documentation on anything in yodlee.  I have managed to correctly handle getLoginForm by just inspecting the JSON objects returned by different sites until I was able to handle all such forms.
What I don't understand is how to get the MFA fields, what makes them different, and how I submit them differently from the regular login form fields.
I'm new to the system, can anyone with some experience explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFA fields are security questions/tokens/images asked as a follow up from the typical login/password (although you'll soon learn there is nothing typical in the obscure world of bank authentication).

You get the MFA fields by calling getMFAResponse (once you've gotten an ItemID from your addItemForContentService1 call) - http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/getMFAResponse

Which you then use to build another form, and take that input and submit it with putMFARequest - http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/putMFARequest

Comment: outdated APIs :(